Allow all users to trigger a data sync to shared directory (groups vs dummy user?)
I have an Ubuntu server with ~6-7 users.  We all use some software that requires some shared files and folders to be regularly updated.  Let's call that shared directory
/opt/science/online-data
Within this are some calibration and data files that are updated on an irregular basis on an external public server not owned by me. I have a cron job that runs an rsync command every day at 5 AM to keep it up-to-date. In everday usage, this folder just needs to be readable by all users (not written to).
However, there are times where the software throws an error indicating that the online-data folder needs to be immediately updated before the software can be used. I'm not always around as admin to run that command. I'd like to set things up so that any of my users can run a script "update_online_data.py" or whatever, and it will trigger the rsync.
I tried doing this by having the online-data folder group set to a specific group "softwaregroup" and giving all users membership, but the users are reporting permission errors. That's probably an error I can figure out (I'm pretty sure this should work.),  but I wonder if there is a more secure way to do this anyway? Right now the group membership could in theory allow them to mess up those files when I really do not want them to do anything other than the rsync. Is there a way to create a command that triggers a non-login user specific to this task to do this and only this?  (I have a vague idea that daemons or services might be a possibility, but I don't have a lot of experience using them in a custom way.)

There are many ways to do this, probably the most traditional is creating an entry
in a sudoers file that allows them to run a certain command under a reserved user id.
A more novel but simple mechanism might be a path-initiated systemd
service. To use it, the users would create a file, say
/opt/science/online-data/UPDATEME, and this would trigger a service unit
to run some command under a reserved user id to do the updates, and then remove the file.
You would create a .path file in /etc/systemd/system/, say
myupdate.path containing
[Unit]
Description=start myupdate.service when UPDATEME file appears
[Path]
PathExists=/opt/science/online-data/UPDATEME
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and another myupdate.service containing
[Unit]
Description=Update files on user request by creating file UPDATEME
[Service]
User=wantedusername
ExecStart=/bin/myupdatefilescript
ExecStartPost=rm -f /opt/science/online-data/UPDATEME

Do not start the service, but do systemctl start myupdate.path for
testing, and enable it for reboots.

Thank you! Just to clarify, I should have them write the UPDATEME file somewhere that has suitable group ownership, right? So perhaps a location like /opt/science/online-data/updatefile/UPDATEME and have only that location writable, rather than the whole online-data folder (if I want to disable them writing there).

Yes, I assumed there was somewhere where they already had write access.
